# keep keycloak from init on loop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, keycloak, react-context

As @react-keycloak/web package is deprecated I tried to make a custom context in order to get the keycloak stuff all of the way throught my react app.

thanks to my friend chat GPT because I had 0 ideas on how to typescript I got that

```
import React, {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  ReactNode,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
} from "react";
import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";

interface KeycloakContextProps {
  keycloak: Keycloak | null;
  authenticated: boolean;
}

const KeycloakContext = createContext<KeycloakContextProps | undefined>(
  undefined
);

export const KeycloakProvider: React.FC<{
  children: ReactNode;
}> = ({ children }) => {
  const authenticatedRef = useRef(false);
  const keycloakInstanceRef = useRef<Keycloak | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initKeycloak = async () => {
      try {
        const keycloak = new Keycloak("/keycloak.json");
        await keycloak.init({
          onLoad: "login-required",
        });
        keycloakInstanceRef.current = keycloak;
        authenticatedRef.current = true;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Keycloak initialization error", error);
      }
    };

    if (!keycloakInstanceRef.current) {
      console.log("Initializing Keycloak...");
      initKeycloak();
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Keycloak state changed:", {
      authenticated: authenticatedRef.current,
      keycloakInstance: keycloakInstanceRef.current,
    });
  }, []);

  const keycloakContextValue: KeycloakContextProps = {
    keycloak: keycloakInstanceRef.current,
    authenticated: authenticatedRef.current,
  };

  return (
    <KeycloakContext.Provider value={keycloakContextValue}>
      {children}
    </KeycloakContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useKeycloak = () => {
  const context = useContext(KeycloakContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useKeycloak must be used within a KeycloakProvider");
  }
  return context;
};
```

You can see it is heavily console logged as I struggled for the last hours. I made a simple homePage

```
const Home: React.FC = () => {
  const { keycloak, authenticated } = useKeycloak();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>App</h1>
      {authenticated ? <p>Authenticated</p> : <p>Not Authenticated</p>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And the whole page is blinking as keycloak just init() on loop apparently. Any ideas ?

[EDIT] moving `<KeycloakProvider>` outside of `<React.StrictMode>` did the trick for the blinking as per said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75256010/react-keycloak-keeps-refreshing) but keycloak is still not available in children

You can see how simple the app is [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/upbeat-newton-m2wqmq)

Comment: Although you can use chatgpt to just make code, you should understand how the code works before ever using it.  Sometimes you can waste much time just trying to fix the errors it generates instead of fixing the question that was asked to it to get the correct results.